# box and whiskers plot

Tags: statistics, median

I am having some troubles understanding what the components of a box and whiskers plot mean.

Let's say I have some observations.

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
```

This is an even number of observations and the median will be $5.5$. The lower quartile will be $3$ and the upper quartile will be $7.5$. According to my textbook, the quartiles divide the statistical material into 4 equally big parts. I can accept that as long as the quartiles are not part of the observations anymore, because otherwise you cannot split 10 into 4 parts with only whole numbers.

Once you have determined what the quartiles are, are the quartile values still part of the observations? Because if yes, I don´t understand how the lower quartile can split the data set into four equally big parts.

Comment: "box and whisKers plot."

Comment: @Did, you can always "edit" the question :)

Comment: @Banach_Tarski56, what exactly is your question because... well you're not asking anything.

Comment: Haha sorry... Once you have determined what the quartiles are, are the quartile values still part of the observations? Because if yes, I don´t understand how the lower quartile can split the data set into four equally big parts.

Comment: In your data, Q3 should be 8, not 7.5.

Comment: The quartiles and median are not quite defined as splitting the data into four equally big parts, especially when the number of observations is not a multiple of $4$.  To make issues slightly more complicated, boxplots actually use *hinges* which sometimes can have marginally [different definitions](http://peltiertech.com/hinges/)